# Custom Post Type doesn't show Draft and Trash Options

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have custom post type "Pdf"section.But there is no options like Draft and Trash..[image: kindly find out this on attachment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must place (delete) some posts in trash bin first to make this options appear.
The same with draft. You must first assign some post as "Draft" in edit screen.

As I see in your screen, all your PDF CPT are published. So there's nothing in trash, and nothing is a draft.

Comment: Thanks a lot.sometimes i stuck with Auto Draft.this posts are doesn't showing up.

Comment: If my answer is correct with your question please tap it as "answear".